# How to pass a string value to resx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, resx, culture

[image]

How to pass a string value as name in order to get its value from resx file. Currently I'm using the above method (see image) to place bilingual data to a Text Box control. Is it possible to pass a string value as Name for resx file and get a value. Please share some code If you have one this before. Thanks in advance

Comment: A .resx file is written in xml, it should be possible to manipulate it outside of visual studio.

Comment: @Rabban , I need to access it inside the visual studio. Actually what I want is

If we want to change the Text property of TextBox1 I can simply add a new record in the resx file by specifying TextBox1.Text as Name and Desired translated string as Value. If I want to get the translated value to a string variable, how can I pass it to the resx file since string value does not have a property.

Ex:
String value1=//translated_value;

How to pass this value1 to the resx file. What is the format??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new .resx file and  add new value using `ResXResourceWriter` like

```
 using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@".\Resources.resx"))
 {
     resx.AddResource("StringKey1", "s1");
     resx.AddResource("StringKey2", "s2");

 }
```

Here you find more about [working with .resx Files Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want get some key from exist resource file you can get it using `ResourceManager`

```
 ResourceManager myManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resource));
 string myString = myManager.GetString("TextBox.Text");
 string myString2 =  Resource.TextBox_Text;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an existing resource file to use your code?

Comment: What you mean use? Only get or adding new , editing exist values also?

Comment: How to add the same name& value to existing resx file? I have used the same code but it throws error saying  Error: Value does not fall within the expected range. This is not a code error. Code is running without error but when I try to read or open the resx file it says the above given error.